# Class inheritance in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm a bit confused about an error that I'm getting:

> Undefined method 'getAsArray'. The method name must start with either
>   findBy or findOneBy!

`getAsArray()` is a method in my repository class, it's called in `PostsController.php` like so:

```
$categoriesList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AirBlogBundle:Category')->getAsArray();
```

`CategoryRepository.php` is defined like this:

```
namespace Air\BlogBundle\Repository;

class CategoryRepository extends TaxonomyRepository
{

}
```

It extends `TaxonomyRepository` that lives in the same namespace.

`TaxonomyRepository.php` is defined like so:

```
namespace Air\BlogBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class TaxonomyRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function getQueryBuilder(array $params = array()) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

        $qb->select('t, COUNT(p.id) as postsCount')
                ->leftJoin('t.posts', 'p')
                ->groupBy('t.id');

        return $qb;
    }

    public function getAsArray() {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->select('t.id, t.name')
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getArrayResult();
    }

}
```

Why am I getting the "undefined method getAsArray" error?

Comment: Does using this method with `AirBlogBundle:Taxonomy` repository work?

Comment: I've now got rid of the inheritance all together and put the methods directly in `CategoryReposiotry.php` and am still getting the error. Is it possible that the erro is caused by the fact that `PostsController.php` lives in `AirAdminBundle` while `CategoryReposiotry` lives in `AirBlogBundle` ? I'm not sure, I'm referring to the repo with `getRepository('AirBlogBundle:Category')` which should find the repository in another bundle.

Comment: AFAIK, having its repo in another bundle than the controller *shouldn't* be a problem. Also, can you update your question with your newly created code?

Comment: Did you forget to add `repositoryClass` to `@ORM\Entity` annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this error occurs when you forget to specify the repository class inside your entity class. Try modifying to the Entity annotation of your entity class to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category {}
```